# Form Error Validation with alert

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a function that will return an alert if the form was not filled out "error has occured" and if all fields are completed then the alert is "Form submitted successfully". My problem is that if there is an error then the alert "error has occured" fires and when I fill out the incomplete fields and submit the form the "error has occured" fires again because it already exists on the page. How do I ignore any current errors that were already alerted or clear current error alerts so that I can try to validate the form again?

any help is greatly appreciated.

this is my form test page that was built in Salesforce Pardot: http://go.esri.com/l/82202/2016-05-09/2jzdrk

```
<script>
function submitVerify() {
    var formError = document.querySelector("#pardot-form .errors").innerHTML;

    if (formError === "Please correct the errors below:") {
        alert("error has occured");
    } else {
        alert("Form submitted successfully");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: create a snippet of your validation code, it doesn't seem correct way.

Comment: The function that performs the input validation should empty the `.errors` DIV at the start, and then add to it when it detects errors.

Comment: Can you provide more code? it is really hard to get a grasp on what's happening with so little code.

Answer (score 1):

Before alerting that there's an error, empty out your errors field, like this:

```
<script>
function submitVerify() {
    var formError = document.querySelector("#pardot-form .errors").innerHTML;

    if (formError === "Please correct the errors below:") {
        alert("error has occured");

        // <=== reset error message here
        document.querySelector("#pardot-form .errors").innerHTML = null;
    } else {
        alert("Form submitted successfully");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the reset error message but I still get the error alert on re-submit. As a work around maybe I will have the error messages disappear when the error is fixed.

Comment: Do you ever get the alert "Form submitted successfully" to work?  Try entering `document.querySelector("#pardot-form .errors").innerHTML` into your javascript console to see what the output is.  If it's meets your first condition, then it will alert that an error has occurred.  Try to reset that before you return from the submitVerify function